# How could I cut off text after a keyword?

Tags: php, string, substring

So say I would write something like `<break>` and it would show everything before `<break>` out of

```
$text = "I like apple pies<break>Do you like Apple pies?";
```

So it should only output

```
I like apple pies
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$text = "I like apple pies<break>Do you like Apple pies?";

list($result) = explode('<break>',$text,2);
```

Comment: <3, big duh on my part. Especially like the elegance of using `list()`

Comment: `list($result) = explode('<break>',$text,2);` is more efficient, especially if the string is long after the `<break>` mark (php doesn't have to search the whole string).

Answer (score 3):

As a function:

```
function BeforeBreak($input)
{
    return stristr($input, '<break>', true);
}
```

Note this functionality requires PHP 5.3.0.

[stristr documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php)

Comment: Please note that this will perform a case-insensative search for `<break>`. The function would be a great idea, +1.

Comment: This is done to accept `<BREAK>` as well, but use `strstr` instead if the case sensitivity is important.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$text = "I like apple pies<break>Do you like Apple pies?";
$texplode = explode('<break>',$text);
echo $texplode[0];
```

read up on [php explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$good = substr( $bad, 0, strpos( $bad, "<break>" ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

this will give you what you want:

```
<?
   $output = strstr($text, '<break>', true);
?>
```

if you have multiple occurrences it's a good idea to use

```
<?
   $text = 'a<break>b<break>c<break>d';
   $output = explode('<break>', $text);

   // the output will be
   // array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
?>
```

Comment: Please note that you will need to have PHP 5.3.0 installed to be able to use the `before_needle` parameter. Nice answer though, +1.